# Saving a files in LibreOffice to .pdf

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, doc

I was looking to save a file from a .docx file to a .pdf file. I believed this worked in LibreOffice but when I tried to save the file as a .pdf, the option wasn't there.

Is there a .pdf file save function for LibreOffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 'File' menu of LibreWriter, you can select 'Export as PDF', or there is a toolbar butten (next to the save icon on my computer) which does the same thing.

Comment: Brilliant, I thought it was a built in feature but couldn't for the life of me find it. Thanks Charles!